# WebMethods: How to invoke My Webmethods Server business calendar from an Integrated Server Java Service?

Tags: webmethods

What I am attempting to do in a nutshell:
 I am trying to access the corporate calendar that was created using the administrator login in the My Webmethods Server from a Java service I am attempting to write. The service would take the calendar, (containing workdays, holidays and other time off) and call another service that would take the total days a task has been "alive" (since creation) and subtract the non work days giving a total work days the task has been "alive."

There is a package under com.webmethods.sc.calendar That does have a class ICalendarManager.class, which has a method: getCalendarByID() But I don't believe this is what I need.

First step of my process: Get the corporate calendar......I am fairly new to webmethods and have absolutely no idea of even where to begin with this, please point me in the right direction!

Comment: Have you tried with the ICalendarManager? Have you checked in the documentation?